# Action Bar items not working when clicked

Tags: android, xml

I'm having an unusual issue here. My action bar was working properly then i went an tested it now and it totally stop. When pressed, they give no response. One is a back button and the other is a send button. Both of which aren't working. Here is my code for the Menu

ActivityOne.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_send, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_send:
            new PostUpLoad().execute();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

menu_send.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".ActivityOne">

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_send"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/send"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
 </menu>
```

Everything seems fine but they aren't working at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `R.id.home` with `android.R.id.home`.

Comment: I'm now getting and error with R.id.action_send:
It gives an error, that it cannot be resovled

Comment: Only replace `R.id.home` do NOT replace `R.id.action_send`

Comment: Okay, gonna try it now.

Comment: it worked thanks. Just need to figure the other out. I bet its my code that's causing that one to not work. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing breaks in your switch case, and I'm not sure about returning true in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_send, menu);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.home:
        super.onBackPressed(); //might use finish() instead
        break;

    case R.id.action_send:
        new PostUpLoad().execute();
        break;

    default:
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Oh, i thought the returns would make up for that though. Gonna try it and see if works.

Comment: Let us know how it works, and mark as solved if it does!

Comment: The return true is fine in this case (you return true if you handle the click). I believe super.onOptionsItemsSelected(item) just returns false. Also returning inside a switch will obviously end execution of the switch since it's returning out the the method so this is also not an issue.

Comment: @AshkanShams, getting the same issue. :(.